# Pandas - inplace, view, copy confusion

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having an issue with Pandas dataframes.
It seems that Pandas/Python generate a copy of the DF somewhere in my code as opposed to performing the modifications to the original DF.

In the code below, "update_df" still sees the DF with a "file_exists" column, which should have been removed by the previous function.

MAIN:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_main = load_df()
    clean_df2(df_main)
    update_df(df_main, image_path_main)
    .....
```

clean_df2

```
def clean_df2(df): #remove non-existing files from DF
    df['file_exists'] = True # add column, set all to True?
    .....
    df = df[df['file_exists'] != False] #Keep only records that exist
    df.drop('file_exists', 1, inplace=True)  # delete the temporary column
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)  # reindex if source has gaps
```

update_df:

```
def update_df(df, image_path): #add DF rows for files not yet in DF
    print(df)
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I think when you do:

```
df = df[df['file_exists'] != False]
```

You've created a copy of the original df.

To make it work, you can change your function to:

```
def clean_df2(df): #remove non-existing files from DF
    df['file_exists'] = True # add column, set all to True?
    .....
    return df
```

And when you call clean_df2(df), do the following:

```
df = clean_df2(df)
```

Comment: Better yet, change the line to `df.drop(df['file_exits'] != False, inplace=True)`

Comment: That's another option. A copy can be easily made inside a function. Returning the final df is probably a safer option.

Comment: I suppose, but oftentimes you want to avoid copying dataframes for memory reasons.